# How find the range of $4a+2b$

Tags: calculus, inequality, quadratics

let $a\ge 0,b\ge 0$,and such that

> $$(a-2)^2+(b-1)^2=5$$

find the range of $4a+2b$

my try:

**use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality**

> $$[(a-2)^2+(b-1)^2][16+4]\ge (4a-8+2b-2)^2$$
>   so
>   $$-10\le 4a+2b-10\le 10$$
>   so
>   $$0\le 4a+2b\le 20$$
>   But this problem anwser is 
>   $$4a+2b\in \{0\}\bigcup [4,20] $$

where is wrong? Thank you.and someone have other nice methods?

Comment: What's wrong is you haven't used the conditions $a\ge0$, $b\ge0$. You can only get $0\lt4a+2b\lt4$ if you violate one of those conditions.

Comment: sorry,I don't understand your meaning,can you give your full solution?

Comment: The graph of the equation is a circle, center $(2,1)$, passing through $(0,0)$. For each $k$, $4a+2b=k$ is a line. You want to know, for which values of $k$ does the line meet the circle in the 1st quadrant. Draw a picture, and do a little algebra, and then post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

f(a,b)=4a+2b ========a^2+b^2
if you catch 4a+2b from the circle eqution
so look at this idea

Comment: min distance from origin is 0 and max root of (20)=2root(5)

Comment: But the question asks for more than the max and min, it asks for the range --- which is *not* everything between the max and the min, because of the non-negativity condition on the variables.

Answer (score 2):

Let $4a+2b=p$.

Hence, $b=\frac{p}{2}-2a$ and $$(a-2)^2+\left(\frac{p}{2}-2a-1\right)^2=5$$
and $\Delta\geq0$ with checking $a=b=0$ gives the answer.